# Android Studio Flamingo failed to launch an application because use wrong applicationId

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, adb

After I update android studio ide from Dolphin to Flamingo, when I press run button the ide failed to launch my app.

As I see the different between 2 version of Ide is

Android Studio Dolphin use this command to launch

```
adb shell am start -n "com.freeman.bluedev/com.freeman.color.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
```

Android Studio Flamingo use this

```
adb shell am start -n "com.freeman.color/com.freeman.color.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER --splashscreen-show-icon
```

As you can see that

Android Studio Flamingo use wrong applicationId(com.freeman.color)

Android Studio Dolphin use correct applicationId(com.freeman.bluedev)

Does anyone has a solution?

Please Help.

Or,

Does anyone know where to report is issue to google?

You can clone this project on this link

[link to clone my project](https://github.com/juckrit/color)

Comment: Are you sure you have selected the correct flavor? I can't see which Android Gradle plugin you use but on modern versions of AGP you should not declare the `package` attribute in AndroidManifest.xml. Instead only use `namespace` value in gradle config. May be because `package` and `namespace` don't match and thus AS is confused?

Comment: Thank for you advice @Robert. I already used namespace and pushed to git repo. But it still not working.

Comment: Your git repo look nice clean from all Android Studio settings. Have you tried to make a fresh clone of your repo and open it as a new project in AS? May be AS has cached some outdated values in some config file you do normally not edit as developer.

Comment: I already clean my gradle using "sudo rm -Rf ~/.gradle" and then invalidate cache and restart ide then run again but no luck, not working

Comment: I had more the `.idea` folder in mind. It can happen that AS does not correctly update them